# Azure webapp add deploymentLocalGitUrl after create

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I'm trying out https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-html and of course, I'm not following stuff to the letter.

I already have a webapp (and the resource plan and stuff). I just want to want to add the local git stuff. There's this property deploymentLocalGitUrl that should be there when I list the properties of the app in the CLI, but it's not there. How can I add this, either through the CLI or the dashboard?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers, Eric!

Comment: Hi Joy, thanks for your quick response. I'll be sure to test as soon as possible. Cheers, Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a normal situation.

Per my test, you could refer to the screenshots.

I created a web app with `--deployment-local-git`, we could find the `deploymentLocalGitUrl` in the operation result.

[image]

Then I use `az webapp show -n <webappname> -g <resourcegroupname>` to get the properties of the web app. We will not see the `deploymentLocalGitUrl`.

[image]

But we could find it in the azure portal.

[image]

So, if you want to add the property, you could set it in the azure portal.

[image]

After setting it, you will be able to find the property mentioned in the screenshot above.

Comment: using the portal (lower two images) did the trick for me. Took a while (regular work and stuff but also) because the portal page was a bit mangled. The right column (Choose source) was way to the right, outside of the view on the screen. Silly mistake, but the default layout wasn't quite helpful.

I'm all good now, thanks for the answer, Joy!

Answer (score 3):

```
gitdirectory=<Replace with path to local Git repo>
username=<Replace with desired deployment username>
password=<Replace with desired deployment password>
```

After creating webapp on azure, configure the website for deployment via git. Set the account-level deployment credentials.

```
$ az webapp deployment user set --user-name $username --password $password
```

This command will return the Git endpoint to push to which includes the UserName.

```
$ az webapp deployment source config-local-git --name mywebapp --resource-group myResourceGroup
```

It returns as below:

```
{
  "url": "https://username@mywebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/mywebapp.git"
}
```

With the endpoint in hand, cd to the git repo and set up a new remote in Git named azure.

```
$ cd $gitdirectory    //remember to git init before you cd

$ git remote add azure https://username@mywebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/mywebapp.git
```

Finally, you could deploy the application to azure.

```
git push azure master
```

The properties you could see in portal as below:
[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/app-service-cli-deploy-local-git) and this [one](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/nodejs-deployment/deploy-website).

Comment: "This command will return the Git endpoint to push to which includes the UserName" . This is exactly what I needed.  Thx.